# SharePoint always retracts my Add-In

Tags: 2013, solution-deployment, retraction

Everytime I deploy my custom Add-In to my SharePoint-Server it retracts and unistalls all the data including lists and stuff (in which I always need to fill in a bunch of data).

SharePoint even retracts everything if I just change a single line of code in a javascript file. Which shouldn't be a trigger for a whole retract.

Isn't the normal behaviour to push the new state of changes to the existing add-in if there are only changes on not-Feature-related files?

Why is SharePoint so annoying in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the add-in instead of deploying it again, to not lose your changes.

Follow below links for more info:

1. [Update add-in web components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn265911.aspx)
2. [Update host web components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn265912.aspx)

Also, if you are using sharepoint hosted add-in, you can use [Fast Deploy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCurranMVP.SPFastDeploy) to deploy files like JS and CSS.